# Метод, принимающий значения типа List<>

Tags: java

Есть класс `Book`, который содержит поля типа `String` такие как `Название книги, автор, издательство, тип переплета, год издательства, кол-во страниц и цена` и методы, которые возвращают данные значения типа `String`:

```
class Book{
{
    id_auto_generate++;
}
private static  int     id_auto_generate;
private         int     id = id_auto_generate;

private         String  title,                                          //название книги
                        author,                                         //автор(ы)
                        publishingOffice,                               //издательство
                        bindingType;                                    //тип переплета
private         int     yearOfPublishing,                               //год издательства
                        numberOfPages,                                  //количество страниц
                        price;                                          //цена

public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}

public String getAuthor(){
    return this.author;
}

public String getPublishingOffice(){
    return this.publishingOffice;
}

public int getYearOfPublishing(){
    return this.yearOfPublishing;
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("ID: %03d | Название книги: %17s | Автор(ы): %14s | Издательство: %14s | Тип переплета: %17s | Год издательства: %5d | Кол-во страниц: %5d | Цена ($): %5d", id, title, author, publishingOffice, bindingType, yearOfPublishing, numberOfPages, price);
}

Book(String title, String author, String publishingOffice, String bindingType, int yearOfPublishing, int numberOfPages, int price) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.publishingOffice = publishingOffice;
    this.bindingType = bindingType;
    this.yearOfPublishing = yearOfPublishing;
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

Далее есть класс 'Library', агрегирующий массив типа `Book`:

```
class Library{
    private String nameLibrary;
    private ArrayList<Book> libraryList = new ArrayList<>();

    void addBookToLibrary(Book c){
        libraryList.add(c);
    }

    //список авторов
    List<Book> getAllAuthors(){
        return new ArrayList<>(libraryList);
    }

    //список книг заданного автора
    void getBookByAuthor(String author){
        for(Book b : libraryList)
            if(b.getAuthor() == author) System.out.println(b);
    }

    //список книг заданного издательства
    void getBookByPublishingOffice(String publishingOffice){
        for(Book b : libraryList)
            if(b.getPublishingOffice() == publishingOffice)     System.out.println(b);
    }

    Library(String nameLibrary){
        this.nameLibrary = nameLibrary;
    }
}
```

Далее, мне нужно вывести список книг определенного автора и список книг определенной редакции, делаю я это так:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int     qt = 0;

        //создаем библиотеку
        Library lib = new Library("Gold Library");

        //добавляем книги (много книг, пишу тут только две)
        lib.addBookToLibrary(new Book("Первая книга", "Петров В.В.", "Медиа-Групп", "Интегральный", 2019, 400, 300));
    lib.addBookToLibrary(new Book("Вторая книга", "Иванов В.В.", "Цельсий", "7Б", 2018, 400, 299));


        //ВОТ ЭТОТ КОД НИЖЕ ПОВТОРЯЕТСЯ (1) и (2)
        // (1)найти всех авторов, а если авторы повторяются, узнать сколько раз повторяется автор, столько книг у его и будет
        List<Book> getAllAuthor = lib.getAllAuthors();
        System.out.println("Всего книг в библиотеке: " + getAllAuthor.size());
        System.out.println("Список доступных авторов:");

        for(int i = 0; i < getAllAuthor.size(); i++){
                    qt = 1;         //кол-во книг автора (по умолчанию значение равно 1, т.к. одна книга автора уже имеется в любом случае)
                    for(int j = i+1; j < getAllAuthor.size(); j++){
                        //проверяем по порядку, если автор следующей книги равен текущему, то его удаляем из List, но увеличиваем qt, чтобы знать, сколько у его книг
                        if(getAllAuthor.get(i).getAuthor() == getAllAuthor.get(j).getAuthor()) {
                            qt++;
                            getAllAuthor.remove(j);
                            j--;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("(" + (i) + ") " + getAllAuthor.get(i).getAuthor() + " (кол-во книг данного автора - " + qt + ")");
                }

          //(2) найти издательства
          List<Book> getAllBooks = lib.getAllAuthors();

          for(int i = 0; i < getAllBooks.size(); i++){
                    qt = 1;         //кол-во книг автора (по умолчанию значение равно 1, т.к. одна книга автора уже имеется в любом случае)
                    for(int j = i+1; j < getAllBooks.size(); j++){
                        //проверяем по порядку, если издательство следующей книги равно текущему, то его удаляем из List, но увеличиваем qt, чтобы знать, сколько книг издательтва
                        if(getAllBooks.get(i).getPublishingOffice() == getAllBooks.get(j).getPublishingOffice()) {
                            qt++;
                            getAllBooks.remove(j);
                            j--;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("(" + (i) + ") " + getAllBooks.get(i).getPublishingOffice() + " (кол-во книг данного издательства - " + qt + ")");
                }
    }
}
```

Вопрос: как создать правильно отдельный метод в классе `Main` или в классе `Library`, который в качестве аргумента будет принимать значение, по которому можно будет понять, что искать, либо авторов либо издательства. И потом этот метод вставить в класс `Main` типа так:

```
тип_возвращаемого_значения getInformationAbout(Library lib, AUTHOR){
    //два цикла for, которые будут искать всех авторов, а те авторы, которые повторяются, будет считать сколько раз повторяется
}
```

и

```
тип_возвращаемого_значения getInformationAbout(Library lib, PUBLISHINGOFFICE){
    //два цикла for, которые будут искать издательства
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем нужен такой метод? Второе - если вы называете метод get.. он не должен возвращать void? Третье объекты через нельзя сравнивать через ==. Опишите, пожалуйста, саму задачу, которую пытаетесь решить.

Comment: Возвращать void? Это как вообще?

Comment: j--; - манипуляция переменной цикла внутри цикла, плохой кейс, можно словить трудно отлавливаемый баг

Comment: void - будет выводиться сообщение через `System.out.println(метод, который возвращает String)`

Comment: полностью изменил вопрос, посмотрите вверху темы

Comment: @Z.John, это не объекты, это методы, которые возвращают тип `String`, соответственно я сравниваю значения типа `String`

Comment: String это объекты, и сравниваются они только через equals

Comment: @Z.John, спасибо, приму к сведению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, как Вы собрались делать тип возвращаемого значения `void`...

```
List<Book> getAllAuthors(){
    List<Book> lb = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Book b : libraryList) lb.add(b);
    return lb;
}
```

Данный метод (в котором у вас отсутствуют фигурные скобки после цикла; что является плохой практикой написания код) переписывается куда короче:

```
List<Book> getAllAuthors(){
    return new ArrayList<>(libraryList);
}
```

Ну и сформулируйте вопрос более конкретно; из вашего текущего вообще не понятно - что и для чего вам нужно возвращать

Comment: полностью изменил вопрос, посмотрите в теме вверху

Answer (score 0):

1. Этот метод можно сократить до `return new ArrayList<>(libraryList)`;
2. Вы создаете экземпляр интерфейса `List` с дженериком `Book`, в который помещаете ссылку на `ArrayList` с дженериком `Book`.

По коду:
Вы можете использовать функциональный интерфейс `Function<Book, V>` в качестве аргумента. Тогда код примет следующий вид:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(new Book("a", "1"), new Book("b", "1"), new Book("c", "2"), new Book("d", "1"));
    getInformation(new Library("Russian", books),
                             Book::getAuthor,
                             (String v, Integer n) -> "В данной библиотеке есть " + n + " книг(а)(и) автора " + v); 
}
public static<V> void getInformation(Library library, Function<Book, V> getControl, speechUses2Vars<V, Integer> speechAboutControl) {
    List<Book> booksFromLibrary = library.getBooks();
    Map<V, Integer> controls = new HashMap();
    booksFromLibrary.forEach(a -> {
        controls.put(getControl.apply(a), controls.getOrDefault(getControl.apply(a), 0) + 1);
    });
    for(Map.Entry<V, Integer> entry : controls.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(speechAboutControl.getSpeech(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface  speechUses2Vars<T, V>{
    String getSpeech(T t, V v);
}
```

Вывод:

> В данной библиотеке есть 3 книг(а)(и) автора 1
>   В данной библиотеке есть 1 книг(а)(и) автора 2

Если вам нужно сказать "В библиотеке libraryname ...", то просто добавьте еще один параметр в функцию функционального интерфейса.

Comment: Спасибо за решение, сложновато, буду разбираться с кодом.

Comment: полностью изменил вопрос, посмотрите вверху темы

Comment: @n199a удивительно, но я правильно понял ваш вопрос в его первой редакции. Ответ работает. Если что-то не понятно - задавайте вопросы.

Comment: как бы правильно ответить) Видимо у меня не хватает пока что знаний, читая ваш код. В частности, относительно `static<V>`. Какой раздел Java необходимо почитать, чтобы понимать суть этого? Может есть какой-нибудь пример проще?)

Comment: @n199a это дженерик. Применяю я его потому, что мы не знаем, какого типа будет свойство, по которому мы будет считать. по-хорошему нужно писать <тип дженерика>functionName, чтобы указать тип дженерика явно. Но его можно указать и неявно, если он используется в параметрах - в нашем случае это Function<Book, V> getControl. А потом, когда тип дженерика указан, дженерик просто заменяется в коде на указанный тип

Comment: тогда буду ознакамливаться с дженериком